# Cannot change the colour of the button of my android application in Android studio

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android studio. I started to create a mobile application. I need to add a white color button to my mobile application. I just drag and drop a button and it shows as blue color in the Android studio design as well as in my phone. After I created a `button.xml` to change the color of the button. But still not fixed that problem.

- My phone is : **Samsung M21**
- Android studio version: **2020.3.1 Patch 3**

I will add my code of the button and screenshots of the android design as well as in my phone.

This is the problem I have.

This screenshot is in the Android Design.

[image]

This screenshot is on my mobile phone.

[image]

**code of the button (activity_to_do.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".todo.ToDo">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**button.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="50px"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
</shape>
```

can anyone help me? I need to change the color of the button to white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be solved by changing background tint opacity (Alpha in ARGB) to 0%.
However, as text color and background color are same and white, you won't see text. So below is the updated activity_to_do.xml with black as font color.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".todo.ToDo">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:text="Button"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    app:backgroundTint="#00FFFFFF"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

You can also use GUI for changing background tint.

1. Click on your button.
2. On the attributes, search for "tint" in search bar.
3. Select background tint and set value to "#00FFFFFF"